# Kosher Quizzing  

Tags: riddle, yoreh-deah

What is it that you have two items one thing that starts off Kosher and ends up non Kosher by putting something that starts off non kosher and ends up Kosher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INGREDIENTS:

- 1 piece freshly-slaughtered, deveined but still bloody, kosher meat; preferably soaked in medium-temperature water for half an hour.  DO NOT EAT THIS MEAT!
- Large quantity of kosher salt.  You can eat some of this salt if you want to.

DIRECTIONS:

- Apply salt very generously to meat.  Wait an hour.  Triple-rinse the meat.

YIELDS:

- 1 piece of kosher meat.
- Large quantity of non-kosher salt.

---

Note that the salt is non-kosher only because of the blood it absorbed; for instance, while non-kosher flavorings are not nullified in large mixtures, this salt would be nullified because it's the blood (a non-flavoring) not the salt that's actually non-kosher.

Similarly, the Shach and Taz debate whether a halachic status of *chezkas unsalted* exists; as the change from before salting to afterwards is a physical one, not a halachic one.

Furthermore, bloody meat is not subject to the rule of "something that can be made permissible [*davar sheyeish lo matirin*] is not nullified", as what you really have here is meat (that's always kosher) mixed with blood (that's always non-kosher).  All that salting does is unmix the two, it doesn't halachamagically *permit* the blood.

Comment: Wow fast and complete answer with Mareh Mekomos and all!!

Comment: But you can eat that meat.  As long as you eat it raw, the blood doesn't have the status of blood that moves from place to place.  It is the cooking process that makes the meat non-kosher.  See the Rosh and Tosefos on Chullin 14a, Pri Magidim's intro to Melicha fourth paragraph, Pri Chadash 67:1, Sifsai Da'as there, Taz 69:27, Mishbatos Zahav there, as well as the Yalkut Yosef(can't remember specific seif there).

Comment: The red liquid you see in the packages of raw meat is mostly water mixed with a protein called myoglobin

Comment: Wasn't talking about tzir, was talking actual dam in the meat.  Until it is dam shpiresh m'makom l'makom it is kosher.  It is the cooking process that changes that, because the blood will move in the meat(hence al pi halakha it can be roasted to make it kosher as well/also the only way we kasher liver).