# There is Always Blood in Meat

Tags: kashrut-kosher, blood

All meat has at least some blood in it, no matter the form of kashering , salting or cooking. How much is too much? Why don't the red/pink blood-containing "juices" make meat eating forbidden?

Comment: Can you [edit] to source your claims?

Comment: related http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/24208/8291

Comment: Welcome Fresdo. dam evarim is a notion that perhaps you do not know.

Comment: neither the redness nor the liquid leftover in the meat is blood but there is a specific protein in the meat which makes the meat red. the liquid is water.

Comment: duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7914/11501 ?

Comment: Hi Fredso, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! You will find a very similar one already asked and answered so hopefully this will help you as well. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: See Yalkut Yosef Melicha(Siman 69) who discusses as to whether that which you wrote that salt never extracts all the blood is true.

Comment: @MosheRabbi I think that I saw recently on the OU (or maybe it was CRC) a page that discusses how to properly make liver kosher. I think it stated that you need 2 requirements - 1 that the blood must be completely drained out, so no pink arteas are allowed in the liver at all and 2 - even after all that, the liver must still be salted. My understanding from this is that the salt is important no matter what because the roasting never extracts all the blood either.

Answer (score 2):

What you call blood is not what the Torah calls blood

It has nothing to do with the amount

only blood that is separated from the meat, or gathered together or moved (started to get out and stopped)  is called blood  (and biblically only if it was not salted

A raw piece of meat is kosher if you wash the surface

[Yd 67](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.67)

[PRI megodim intro to laws of salting](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4445)

The juices after the salting are called wine of the meat and not blood

> מליחה חמרא דבשרא הוא ולא דם

Comment: How do you know blood that hasn't separated isn't called blood? Perhaps it's permitted blood?

Comment: @DoubleAA It is a guess, since if the Torah says do not eat blood, and this is edible so it must not be legally "blood" that the Torah forbade